# dictionary produces empty key/Values

Tags: python-2.7, csv, dictionary

I'm trying to map row values on a .csv file using other reference files. The original .csv looks like this:

```
PROBE,8988,8981,8878,8983
1371844,0.011,-0.018,-0.032,-0.034
1386013,0.034,0.225,-0.402,0.418
1390154,0.145,-0.108,-0.421,-0.048
1393851,-0.146,-0.026,-0.101,-0.011
```

The reference .csv that I used to make the dictionary looks like this:

```
PROBE, Title, Gene
1390154, Cellular, Becn1
1371844, Liver, Vcp
1393851, Kidney, Lypla2
1386013, Heart, Ube2d2
```

Ideally I can achieve this:

```
PROBE   8988   8981   8878   8983
Vcp  0.011 -0.018 -0.032 -0.034
Ube2d2  0.034  0.225 -0.402  0.418
Becn1  0.145 -0.108 -0.421 -0.048
Lypla2 -0.146 -0.026 -0.101 -0.01
```

This is what I tried:

```
import csv
import pandas as pd

reader = csv.reader(open('C:\Users\Troy\Documents\ExPSID.csv')) #Open reference .csv file     
result = {}
for row in reader:
    key = row[0]
    result[key] = row[2]
    dict = result #Configure dictionary

df = pd.read_csv('C:\Users\Troy\Documents\ExPS2.txt', index_col=0) #Fetch unmapped .csv
df.replace({"PROBE": dict}) #Use dictionary to map Id's to genes
```

It throws a **"ValueError: Replacement not allowed with overlapping keys and values".**

However, I know why this is, because if i print dict, I get:

```
{'': '', ' ': '', '1390154': 'Becn1', '1386013': 'Ube2d2', 'Probe  ': 'Gene', '1371844': 'Vcp', '1393851': 'Lypla2'}
```

It prepends my dictionary with two empty key:value sets. If I manually delete those, df.replace({"PROBE": dict}) works correctly and all is well.

So my question is, **is there a way I can alter this script so that I don't have to manually delete the prepended key:value sets? Is there a better way to do this overall?**

I'm clearly new at Python, so if this a dumb question I'll gladly own it :P

---

P.S.: If i wanted to map the columns also, using another reference .csv like this:

```
Experiment, Array, Drug
8983, Genechip, Famotidine
8878, Microarray, Dicyclomine
8988, Genechip, Etidronate
8981, Microarray, flunarizine
```

Can I simply replace the "row" in the aforementioned code to "col"? When I tried that, it just spit back the original file with no new values mapped....

I appreciate the help everyone!

Comment: I see nothing in your code that could magicaly put those "empty" keys in your dictionnary, so my guess is that you may have a few empty lines in your csv file that are responsible for this.
I would suggest you `print` row[0] and row[2] for each line to find where the empty values are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  import pandas as pd
  If i understood you correctly you want to achieve something like this from the two sets you have:

         8988   8981   8878   8983
PROBE                             
Vcp     0.011 -0.018 -0.032 -0.034
Ube2d2  0.034  0.225 -0.402  0.418
Becn1   0.145 -0.108 -0.421 -0.048
Lypla2 -0.146 -0.026 -0.101 -0.011

pandas merge() function can help you achieve what you want: 

df1 = pd.read_csv('{path_to_original}/org.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('{path_to_reference}/reference.csv', delimiter=', ', engine='python')
df3 = df1.merge(df2)
df4 = df3.set_index('Gene').drop(['PROBE', 'Title'], axis=1)
df4.index.name = 'PROBE'
print(df4)

If you take a look at your reference file that has space after delimiter comma i.e why it is mentioned as delimiter ', ' while reading the csv.
```

Comment: This is perfect for the mapping the index. I hadn't thought about using `merge`.